# Is it possible to use jQueryUI Datepicker instead of the w2ui builtin date picker?

Tags: w2ui

I am using jqueryUI datepicker through out my app, and would like to use that in one of the date fields on a w2popup or w2form.  I've tried $('#field-id').datepicker() after I open the form, but it does not work.

Is there a way to make that work?

Answer (score 1):

You can't apply the jQueryUI datepicker to a w2ui date field, because there's no way to prevent the w2ui date popup from openening.

You can however apply the jQueryUI datepicker to a "normal" w2ui field, so you can have the w2ui look and feel on the field and also use the datepicker.

Note that when using w2ui layout/forms, you're most likely already using a z-index, whether you want or not, while jQueryUI's datepicker has a default z-index of 2.

To circumvent this, you can set the z-index as follows:

```
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        beforeShow: function() {
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('.ui-datepicker').css('z-index', 99999999999999);
            }, 0);
        }
    }).w2field('text');
});
</script>
```

Or you could write your own w2ui field that opens a jQueryUI datepicker:

http://w2ui.com/web/docs/form/fields-custom